# Python script on adding connection from linkedin

Tags: python, python-2.7, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use python-linkedin library here https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin to send an invitation to LinkedIn contact via script

But on the following code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

API_KEY = 'wFNJekVpDCJtRPFX812pQsJee-gt0zO4X5XmG6wcfSOSlLocxodAXNMbl0_hw3Vl'
API_SECRET = 'daJDa6_8UcnGMw1yuq9TsjoO_PMKukXMo8vEMo7Qv5J-G3SPgrAV0FqFCd0TNjQyG'

RETURN_URL = 'https://localhost:8000'

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL) #, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
```

I get

> The redirect_uri does not match the registered value

when pasting authentication.authorization_url into the browser.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you grant access to the application, you will be redirected to the return url with the following query strings appended to your RETURN_URL
2. Take the key value after `http://localhost:8000/?code=`
3. add it after the `authentication.authorization_code = "the code provided"`
4. use `authentication.get_access_token()`
5. then `application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token='the token provided')`

Quick usage example:

```
from linkedin import server
application = server.quick_api(KEY, SECRET)
application.get_profile()
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't connect either with the default link give me a 404 error. Do you have worked previously with this library ?

Comment: still confused ... First how to grant access to the application .... I have just created it from linkedin and got key and secret ... After that second step is also not clear : which value to take  ? thanks in advance

Comment: How do I request the an Authorization Code ?

Comment: I do thing you have to jump back into the documentation, you are missing too much info to get there. Sorry, at this point I will just copy past the documentation to answer to your question, which is not compliant to Stack Overflow goals.